# camel ftp seems hang forever

Tags: java, ftp, apache-camel, apache-commons-net

I got a camel route that is like hanged forever, not sure if it's Camel or Ftp client problem. The ftp component have soTimeout set as 60000. Any help is appreciated.

> Version of components:
>   camel-ftp: 2.9.0
>   Commons Net: (2.2)

Thread dump:

```
"Camel (some-ftp-route) thread #57 - ftp://user@ftphost/folder" Id=338 in RUNNABLE (running in native)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:264)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:306)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:158)
  - locked java.io.InputStreamReader@6a3f933a
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:167)
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:136)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:299)
  - locked java.io.InputStreamReader@6a3f933a
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:362)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__getReply(FTP.java:295)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP._connectAction_(FTP.java:365)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._connectAction_(FTPClient.java:630)
at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:164)
at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:184)
at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.FtpOperations.connect(FtpOperations.java:91)
at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.RemoteFileConsumer.connectIfNecessary(RemoteFileConsumer.java:144)
at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.RemoteFileConsumer.recoverableConnectIfNecessary(RemoteFileConsumer.java:123)
at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.RemoteFileConsumer.prePollCheck(RemoteFileConsumer.java:56)
at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.poll(GenericFileConsumer.java:100)
at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:139)
at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:91)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:317)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:150)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:204)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

I'm just surprise that soTimeout didn't work. It hanged for almost 1 day...

Comment: I have noticed this happening in 2.12.2 also. It is hard to reproduce it though...

Comment: Maybe something to do with this:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-8088

Comment: This sounds very much like the issue @DakotaBrown points to. That should really be the answer here.

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed in Camel 2.13.4, 2.14.2 and 2.15.0

The commit on Camel 2.15.0 is the following:
https://github.com/apache/camel/commit/3774c01e71cf8715e90673328655fd426242e7ba